# Почему псевдоклассы не работают в Google Chrome и IE

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, focus

(!!!Есть похожая тема, но я не нашёл в ней ответы на свои вопросы, поэтому огромная просьба не помечать мой вопрос как дубликат!!!)

В браузерах Google Chrome, Firefox, IE submit работает как надо. И всё остальное в Firefox тоже работает так, как надо. Но в IE не работает псевдокласс focus (текст просто стирается при нажатии на элемент формы). А в Хроме не появляются стили указанные для класса text (т.е. текст-подсказка для ввода не выделяется красным цветов) и не работает focus(текст не выделяется зелёным при нажатии на поле ввода текста).  Что с этим делать? Как это исправить?

```css
  input {
   color: #ffffff;
  }
   input.submit:hover {
    background-color: #665544;
   }
   input.submit:active {
    background-color: chocolate;
   }
   input.text {
    color: red;
   }
   input.text:focus {
    color: green;
   }
```

```html
  <input class="text" type="text" placeholder="Введите электронную почту"/>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить запрос"/>
```

Comment: [работает же](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OrvZbG?editors=10000)

Comment: Если вы хотите раскрасить placeholder, то нужно красить псевдоэлемент `::placeholder`, а не сам input. А для IE это нормальное стандартное поведение и с этим ничего не поделать

Comment: @andreymal покажите пожалуйста на примере. У меня не работает. Может я что-то не так делаю

Comment: @andreymal Вы возможно меня неправильно поняли. Я не хочу раскрасить placeholder. По идее всё должно работать так: изначально цвет текста в элементе формы красный. А при нажатии на форму цвет текста меняется на зелёный и не только цвет placeholder, но и любого текста, который я ввожу в форму. И в Firefox всё работает как надо